# How to handle nulls in RxJava 2.x?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, rx-java2

Suppose I have

```
// binding dialog open to excel 2
      JavaFxObservable
         .actionEventsOf(importExcel2)
         .map(actionEvent -> chooseFile())
         .filter(Objects::nonNull)
         .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
         .subscribe(file -> {
            sourceFile.setFile(file);
            opRunner.runOp(ImportExcelTable2Op.class);
         });
```

The fact is `chooseFile()` returns `null` when file select is cancelled and streams do not allow `null`s.

What to do then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

1. Turn `map` into a call to `flatMap` which returns `Observable.just(chooseFile())` or `Observable.empty()` based on whether the return value is null.
2. Encode the lack of a result and have `chooseFile()` return `Maybe<File>` and turn `map` into `flatMapMaybe`. This more accurately encodes what semantics should be.

Comment: Ah, also I can use `Optional`! Is this the same as `Maybe`?

Comment: Yes, but you would need to unpack that Optional later down the stream to access the actual value. The solution is mostly personal preference at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Create extensions for Observable:

**ObservableExt.kt**

```
typealias Mapper<T, R> = (T) -> R?

fun <T, R> Observable<T>.mapOrEmpty(mapper: Mapper<T, R>): Observable<R> {
    return this.flatMap { item ->
        val mapped = mapper.invoke(item)
        if (mapped != null) {
            return@flatMap Observable.just<R>(mapped)
        } else {
            return@flatMap Observable.empty<R>()
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

any obj:

```
 class Profile{ 
        var id: String? = null 
        var name: String? = null 
        }
```

in case:

```
 val profile = Profile()

 Observable.just(profile)
    .mapOrEmpty { it.name }
```